# Read file and filter values with python

Tags: python

I have an array filled with values from a `python-read` .txt file, I want to break the information from that file with only what interests me, which are the un commented values, `srv2 and srv3`

**SCRIPT**

```
# value filter without comments
outfinally = []
outfinally = [re.split(r'\s\s+|\s*#\s*|\b\d+\b',line) for line in output[0].splitlines()]

for line in outfinally:
    print(line)
```

**ARCHIVE**

```
########################################################################
#
#       Licensed Materials
#
#
#       (C) Copyright. All Rights Reserved
#
#
#       ========================================================
#       Module Information:
#
#       DESCRIPTION:
#       ping.file
#
######################################################################
#srv1       300
10.10.10.1  300
srv2        300
srv3        300
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['', '========================================================']
['', 'Module Information:']
['', '']
['', 'DESCRIPTION:']
['', 'ping.file']
['', '']
['srv2\t', '']
['srv3\t', '']
```

**DESERIED OUTPUT**

```
srv2
srv3
```

Comment: Why not the line '10.10.10.1  300'?

Comment: desired output is hostname

Comment: So, what are the criteria? A non-empty line that doesn't start with '#' or a digit?

Comment: Are the server names within this file random, not just srv2 and srv3, would it work?

Comment: The criteria are the lines that contain only hostname, whatever is beyond that, I wanted to eliminate

Comment: cases may occur as follows:

server name #comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a regex here, just keep the non-empty lines starting with a letter, and keep the first word:

```
test = """
#       ping.file
#
######################################################################

#srv1       300
10.10.10.1  300
srv2        300
srv3        300
srv4   # comments
"""

lines = [line.split()[0] for line in test.splitlines() if line and line[0].isalpha()]
print(lines)
# ['srv2', 'srv3', 'srv4']
```

Or if you want it like this:

```
print('\n'.join(lines))
```

Output:

```
srv2
srv3
srv4
```